# How can I expire my windows password?

Tags: password

I am a software developer, I should test my application for if a user's password is expired. (windows authentication is used) So I want to expire my windows password to provide the test condition. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have Domain Admin rights? or Local admin rights if not in a domain?

You can select the user in either "Active Directory Users and Computers" or "Computer Management". Then you can choose "User must change password at next login".

Or: You can change group policy to force it expired

gpedit.msc..computer config..windows settings..security settings..account policies..password policy